# Horizontally center block with unknown width

Tags: html, css

I have 3 blocks with different widths. I want each block to be centered horizontally and also have the text under the main text have as `text-align:right` towards main text. See the picture

How to do it?

image = http://www.nahraj-obrazek.cz/pt-313937842321.png

Comment: You should post code (html and css) that you have tried so we can help you.

Comment: [jsfiddle][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/QBrQk/



and i want this blog have horizontal centering

Comment: I have written the answer for you. http://jsfiddle.net/QBrQk/10/

Comment: thx guys. Display table is good solution.

Comment: If the content that you want to show are quotes than you should use blockquote and cite tags instead.

Comment: Will you consider to accept the answer that helped you as the right answer? It's the way to encourage stackoverflow members to answer. Just don't leave by saying `Thanks Guys` only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table;` to achieve your desired effect. **[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GKC9q/1)** 
Define `display: table;` to the `div` inside which your both text are and center it by applying `margin: auto;`. For the text that you want to align right, write `text-align: right;` style. That's all.

It's less code as well.

[**AND DEMO FROM FIDDLE YOU PROVIDED**](http://jsfiddle.net/QBrQk/11/)

```
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
div p {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.block
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

p.right
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this:

```
#center {
    text-align: center;
}
.someblock{
    display: table; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.someblock p {
    text-align: right;
}
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/6Mp34/

Answer (score 0):

With unknown width

```
 *, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.wrap {
     text-align: center;
}
.row {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.row:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
.author {
   text-align: right;
   display: block;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/9SqTe/7/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/9SqTe/7/show/